# Iframe does not show the page

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

putting this is the html webpage does not show the page, what is the reason?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://secure.mom.gov.sg/iSubmit/Pages/default.aspx">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I look, I am using chrome v25.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is page should have some information when it's beeing display in iframe. Because it's go throught https site it's probably don't so you can display it in iframe.

More info in second post:

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/39/threadid/240336/scope/posts.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with redirection in https:// site. Your src site doesn't rate iframe as a trustworthy platform. Generally, iframes shouldn't be used for whole pages like that.